# Powershell script to restart service

Tags: powershell

I got this script from a blog and modified it to suit my environment. However I am having problems iterating through the foreach loop and getting the service status or the remote computers ($unregisteredVM).

It seems as if the Get-Service was trying to query the computer executing the script instead of the remote computers.

Also I tried running the portion of the script which grabs the status of the computer and set that variable as the -Computername parameter and it doesn't seem to take it.

$icaservicestate = Get-Service PorticaService -ComputerName $unregisteredVM | select status

What am i missing? Below is the entire code.

```
##Load Citrix Modules
asnp Citrix.*

#Variables for email
[string[]]$recipients = "xxxxx@xxxxxx.com"
$fromEmail = "xxxxx@xxxx.com"
$server = "itopia-us.mail.protection.outlook.com"
$date= Get-Date

##Check for VMs on and unregistered
$unregisteredVMs = Get-BrokerDesktop -RegistrationState Unregistered | Select MachineName
[string]$emailVMs = Get-BrokerDesktop -RegistrationState Unregistered | Select MachineName | ft -wrap -autosize | Out-String

IF (!$unregisteredVMs) {
##Send all clear email
[string]$emailBody = "There were no powered on desktops in an unregistered state."
send-mailmessage -from $fromEmail -to $recipients -subject " XenDesktop Daily Check - $date" -body $emailBody -priority High -smtpServer $server
}
Else {
##If powered-on and unregistered, perform a forceful restart
foreach ($unregisteredVM in $unregisteredVMs)
{
 $icaservicestate = Get-Service PorticaService -ComputerName $unregisteredVM | select status
IF ($icaservicestate = Stopped) {
Set-Service -Name PorticaService -Status Running
}
Else {
sc \\$unregisteredVM start PorticaService
}
 #Write-Host "Hello, I am unregistered: $unregisteredVM"
}

#Send an email report of VMs to be restarted due to being in an unregistered state
[string]$emailBody = "The following desktops were forcefully restarted due to not registering with the DDCs in a timely manner. `n $emailVMs"
send-mailmessage -from $fromEmail -to $recipients -subject " XenDesktop Daily Check - $date" -body $emailBody -priority High -smtpServer $server
}
```

Comment: I think this might help. You have are returning an object array when you just want a list of names. Instead of `$unregisteredVMs = Get-BrokerDesktop -RegistrationState Unregistered | Select MachineName` try `$unregisteredVMs = Get-BrokerDesktop -RegistrationState Unregistered | Select -ExpandProperty MachineName`

Comment: Matt - I tried your suggestion and while I understand the array issue, when adding the expand property and assigning the $testicaserver = Get-Service PorticaService $unregisteredVM | select status it says "cannot find service with service name "PorticaService" I think it's trying to run it on the local VM instead of the remote.

Comment: Just before that line what do you have for `$unregisteredVMs`? It should just be a list of machine names in which case it should work. Is it possible that service is not running?

Comment: I have the following - $unregistedVMs = Get-BrokerDesktop -RegistrationState Unregistered | select -ExpandPropoerty MachineName   - It can't be that the service is running because if I run the powershell command Get-Service PorticaService -Computername Machinename it will actually retrieve the state.

Comment: Sorry I wasnt clear enough. I wanted you to look at the contents of `$unregisteredVMs` to see if it looks as its supposed to.

Comment: Matt - If i don't add the -ExpandProperty then is looks like this MachineName Domain\Machine1 Domain\Machine2.. If I do add the ExpandProperty then it looks the same but without the MachineName column added on top. Either way I can print it as an array say $unregisteredVMs[0] or [1].

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is your entire problem but I don't think this is what you want:

```
IF ($icaservicestate = Stopped)
```

That `assigns` the result of executing a command named `Stopped` to the variable $icaservicestate. I doubt you have a command named `Stopped`. For equality *comparison* use `-eq` and quote `Stopped`:

```
IF ($icaservicestate -eq 'Stopped') { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two potential reasons you may not be getting the result you want.

**First**: In Powershell a single equals sign is the assignment operator.
Your `if` statement line 24 is re-assigning the value of `$icaservicestate` to an error

```
$icaservicestate = Get-Service PorticaService -ComputerName $unregisteredVM | select status
IF ($icaservicestate = Stopped) {
    Set-Service -Name PorticaService -Status Running
}
```

> Use `IF ($icaservice -eq 'stopped') {`

---

**Second**: The line 23 Cmdlet `Get-Service` maybe failing due to line 11 the object you are passing to it

```
$unregisteredVMs = Get-BrokerDesktop -RegistrationState Unregistered | Select MachineName
```

In the above line you've generated an `[array]` of objects with each object having a single property called MachineName.
On line 23 you are trying to pass the objects to the `ComputerName` parameter of the `Get-Service` Cmdlet. To work around this you can use $unregisteredVM.MachineName in the `Get-Service` cmdlet

> $icaservicestate = Get-Service PorticaService -ComputerName $unregisteredVM.MachineName | select status

You can read more about the way property values are passed in the pipeline by typing at the prompt:

`help about_piplines` and looking for 'ByValue' and 'ByPropertyName'

**UPDATE:**

```
if ($icaservicestate -eq 'Stopped') {
    Get-Service -Name PorticaService -ComputerName $unregisteredVM.MachineName | Set-Service -Status Running
}
```

Previously, the line `Set-Service -Name PorticaService -Status Running` would be attempting to start the service on your local machine.

First we grab a reference to the PorticaService on the **remote** machine, then pipe that object to the Set-Service Cmdlet and set the status to running.

Comment: Bob - I understand the -eq and changed that. However regarding the $unregisteredVM.MachineName isn't that passed to the array already from setting $unregisteredVMs = Get-BrokerDesktop -RegistrationState Unregistered | select MachineName ? Either way I modified it to how you say and still not working. Keeps saying that it cannot find the Porticaservice which is not true because If I run Get-Service manually with the actual computer name it will find it.

Comment: Bob answer should work. Maybe it is not expanding the machinename? This is what `-ExpandProperty` was supposed to do. In Bobs answer maybe it needs to be `-ComputerName $($unregisteredVM.MachineName)`. Both mine and bobs answer fix the error so im not sure what the issue is. Maybe put quotes on the service name?

Comment: Matt - I keep getting a "Cannot find any service with service name 'PorticaService' then below another Set-Content: A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'porticaservice' at line 49 char :4

Comment: @DarianJimenez have updated my answer. The Set-Service Cmdlet will attempt to run on localhost unless a "ComputerName" property is specified. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I think your script doesn't work because the machinename you get back from "get-brokerdesktop" is in the format domainname\vdiname. For "get-service -computername" you only need to enter the hostname.
To "isolate" the hostname I'd do:
$unregisteredVM=$unregisteredVM.machinename -replace ("domainname\," ")
$unregisteredVM=$unregsiteredVM.trim()

Now $unregisteredVM should contain only the hostname.